# filtering on date in R

Tags: r

Is there an approach or function to subset or filter data by same ID conditioned on a range of dates for which data were observed? I've looked through many examples using dplyr and lubridate and

```
Something similar maybe?
DF %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter_if(for i %in% Date, between("Date 1 & Date 2 is at least 6 months"))
```

OR

```
DF %>% 
 filter_if(ID = >3 & between("Date 1 & Date 2 is at least 6 months"))
```

Specifically, subset observations if there are at least 3 over any 6 month date range. Would be ok using Cohort_month (as that was extracted from Date column)

My DF is:

---

```
str(DF)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    
25 obs. of  8 variables:
$ ID          : chr  "AbDu" "AbDu" "AbDu" 
"AbDu" ...
$ Reg         : num  29179 32039 35151 
38359 41509 ...
$ Date        : POSIXct, format: "2017-08- 
18" ...
$ Year        : num  2017 2017 2017 2017 
2017 ...
$ Vol1        : num  2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 
2.5 4.9 2.5 2.5 4.9 ...
$ Vol2        : num  2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 
2.5 4.9 2.5 2.5 4.9 ...
$ VolT        : num  10 20 20 20 20 ...
$ Cohort_month: num  8 9 10 11 12 1 1 3 4 
11 ...

DF
# A tibble: 25 x 8
ID     Reg   Date                Year  Vol1  Vol2  VolT
<chr> <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
AbDu  29179 2017-08-18 00:00:00  2017  2.5   2.5  10  
AbDu  32039 2017-09-15 00:00:00  2017   2.5   2.5  20  
AbDu  35151 2017-10-13 00:00:00  2017   2.5   2.5  20  
AbDu  38359 2017-11-10 00:00:00  2017   2.5   2.5  20  
AbDu  41509 2017-12-08 00:00:00  2017   2.5   2.5  20  
AbDu  44732 2018-01-08 00:00:00  2018   2.5   2.5  20  
AbDu  47487 2018-01-31 00:00:00  2018   4.9   4.9  9.8
AbDu  52537 2018-03-14 00:00:00  2018   2.5   2.5  30  
AbDu  57713 2018-05-23 00:00:00  2018   2.5   2.5  30
```

Comment: I think you're looking for a rolling-window operation, where you want to know how many occurred in the `n` months prior to the current. In that case, look at the `zoo` package, it provides rolling functions.

Comment: Can you please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    data_filter = map(
      data,
      ~arrange(.x, Date) %>%
        mutate(
          Date2 = lag(Date, 2),
          MDiff = (difftime(Date, Date2) / 30) %>% as.numeric()
        ) %>%
        filter(MDiff < 6)
    ),
    n_row = map_dbl(
      data_filter,
      nrow
    )
  ) %>%
  filter(n_row > 0) %>%
  select(ID, data_filter) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(-MDiff) %>%
  pmap_df(
    ~filter(df, ID == ..1 & Date <= ..2 & Date >= ..3)
  )
```